# safari cannot play audio in wikipedia

Tags: safari, audio, iphone

The safari in my iPhone 6 can not play audio file in Wikipedia,  for example, the following picture shows a audio file one a Wikipedia page but I cannot play it. what's wrong with it and how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Wikipedia provided solutions for this, [Wikipedia:Media help (audio and video)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Media_help_%28audio_and_video%29)

> It is highly recommended that you use a program which is capable of playing both Vorbis audio and Theora video since these two different media formats are often in the same digital container format, Ogg.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Wikipedia create an account and login. Then you can play ogg files. For example this:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cher_-_Dark_Lady.ogg

For other sites I don't have any specific solutions. But obviously Safari supports ogg, at least in iOS 14.2

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Safari does not support playing OGG files. I haven't checked but there are probably apps available that allow you to play OGG files, a simple App Store search of "ogg audio player" should yield some results.

Answer (score -1):

Safari does not natively support OGG audio files, you need install an OGG plugin. Or just install another web browser on your phone which supports OGG files.

Comment: Thank you, but how to install an OGG on Safari?

Comment: Ogg Drop will encode audio tracks and CD's into vorbis. It also contains a QuickTime component that allows iTunes to play ogg vorbis files. Ogg Drop is entirely free.

Comment: Thanks, it seems Ogg Drop works only on the desktop version, (OS).